# Find sublists that fulfill a given property in Ocaml

Tags: list, ocaml

I have a function that returns every "sublists" from a given list:

```
let rec sublists = function
    [] -> [[]]
    | h::t -> let st = sublists t in
        List.map (function l -> h::l) st @ st;;
```

For example, if you try

sublists [1;4;9;12]

it will return:

[[1; 4; 9; 12]; [1; 4; 9]; [1; 4; 12]; [1; 4]; [1; 9; 12]; [1; 9]; [1; 12];
 [1]; [4; 9; 12]; [4; 9]; [4; 12]; [4]; [9; 12]; [9]; [12]; []]

That are every possible combinations of elements in the list (order doesn't matter)

I have to do a function that returns a different sublists pair that fulfill a given property.

Function must have this type: ('a list -> 'a list -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list * 'a list

For example, if we have the previous list and we try

search (<4) [1;4;9;12]

It will return:

([9;12], [9]) because these lists satisfaces the given condition (<4). Order does not matter, it could return ([9], [12]) instead, or another possible combination.

I'm stucked at this, I have done a function that check if a given list is a sublist of another list:

```
let is_sublist_of l1 l2 =
    let sub = sublists l1 in 
        List.mem l2 sub;;
```

But I think that is useless here. Coul anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just filter the list first and then apply the two first runs of sublist to it ?

```
let filter_sublist f l = 
  let l = List.filter f l in
  let rec sublists = function
    | [] -> [], []
    | h :: t -> 
      let st1, st2 = sublists t in
      h :: st1, st2
  in sublists l
```

The problem here is that `f` is of type `'a -> bool` because I don't understand your type `('a list -> 'a list -> bool)`. What is it supposed to represent ?

Comment: I don't understand either, they have asked me to do it that way :/